# How to execute PHP query (without arguments) from android

Tags: php, android, mysql

how could I invoke this code:

```
<?php
//load and connect to MySQL database stuff
require("config.inc.php");
$query_params = null;

$resetQuery = "UPDATE `items` SET `picked`= 0";
 try {
        $stmt   = $db->prepare($resetQuery);
        $result = $stmt->execute($query_params);
    }
    catch (PDOException $ex) {
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "PHP Database Error!";
    die(json_encode($response));
}
echo "DB reset complete";
?>
```

from android app?
Normally, when there are arguments to pass, I parse JSON object and post it as follows:

```
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(
                    RESET_DB, "POST", params);
```

Comment: Well what does it matter? The arguments are neglected. So you could send rubbish. You could use a GET too.